# Spring JPA Hibernate Maven - Error : No persistence units parsed from {classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml}

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, spring, jpa, maven

While testing the application created in [Getting Started With JPA in Spring 2.0](http://blog.springsource.com/2006/05/30/getting-started-with-jpa-in-spring-20/) tutorial I am getting following error. I have created Maven Project in eclipse. Here is the part of the structure of the project

```
ecotraveler
   src
      main
         java
             com
                enam
         resources
             config
                   applicationContext.xml
   WebContent
       META-INF
           persistance.xml
```

While running test class I am getting `No persistence units parsed from {classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml}`

Can anyone tell what could be the problem? It seems application is unable to find specified path. I double check that WebContet/META-INF is in eclipse build path.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wicket+Spring+JPA+Hibernate: No Persistence Unit Found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873545/wicketspringjpahibernate-no-persistence-unit-found)

Answer (score 4):

You need to put the META-INF directory in you resources directory, not in the WebContent

Answer (score 2):

You spelt "persistence.xml" wrong; it has no "a"